# Use heatmaply to create heatmap with raw values/data without transformations?

Tags: r, data-visualization, heatmaply

When creating a heatmap with `heatmaply::heatmaply()`, some transforms are performed on the raw data. This is evident in the following example where some of the iris dataset is provided, yet hovering over the heatmap shows some negative values (which weren't in the original data provided to `heatmaply()`), and the colorbar on the side also shows negative values as well.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt0vGm.png

```
library(heatmaply)
mat <- iris[1:20, 1:4] %>% as.matrix
p <- heatmaply(mat, 
                   dendrogram = "none",
                   xlab = "", ylab = "", 
                   main = "",
                   scale = "column",
                   margins = c(60,100,40,20),
                   grid_color = "white",
                   grid_width = 0.00001,
                   titleX = FALSE,
                   hide_colorbar = FALSE,
                   branches_lwd = 0.1,
                   label_names = c("Country", "Feature:", "Value"),
                   fontsize_row = 5, fontsize_col = 5,
                   labCol = colnames(mat),
                   labRow = rownames(mat),
                   heatmap_layers = theme(axis.line=element_blank()),
                   colors = rev(c("000000", heat.colors(30)[1:28]))
)

p
```

Different scale to `iris[1:20, 1:4]`:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuMcn.png

#### Question

How can `heatmaply::heatmaply()` be made to generate a heatmap based ***purely on the raw values*** provided (no transformations)?

Note: open to using other packages/functions/suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `scale` argument - the default is "none". Or change it to "none".

```
heatmaply(mat, 
          dendrogram = "none",
          xlab = "", ylab = "", 
          main = "",
          # scale = "column",  # <-- remove this line. Or change to "none"
          margins = c(60,100,40,20), ...
```

[image]